# Requirements for a Timer Job deployment

Tags: 2010, timer-jobs, visual-studio-2012

I created a timer job to kick off a workflow on all items in a List. I followed [this](https://bhandariasb.wordpress.com/2013/06/03/start-workflow-from-custom-timer-job/) template and converted the code to VB.

What do I need to deploy this to my SharePoint site using the command:

```
add-spsolution -literalpath "location of wsp"
```

[This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/Ee231585%28v=VS.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and [this](http://geekswithblogs.net/evgenyblog/archive/2008/01/27/118966.aspx) article are a little confusing. Shouldn't VB already have created everything needed for deployment? 
I got a

```
"Cannot find this file in the manifest file: ..\MyListManifest.xml"
```

After I built it and tried to deploy the wsp file from the debug folder

Comment: You have to package/publish your solution in visual studio, this will create a .wsp file in your debug directory, copy that to a web front end in your farm and run the add-spsolution command with the file path to your wsp you copied.

Comment: I did that. what about the feature, manifest, schema, etc. files?

Comment: all of it is packaged into the wsp automatically for you by VS, the wsp is all you need.

Comment: I'm getting an error (above) when I try to deploy the wsp from the debug folder

Comment: @PT_C you have an option to publish the timer job to file system. Right click on solution and publish.

Comment: @Akhoy i do not have those permissions and the person who does is requiring I do it his way